# Ayuda en Javascript con getElementById

Tags: javascript

Muy buenas a todos, llevo un buen rato intentando y nada... alguien podría corregirme y decirme cuál es mi error? todo el codigo funciona bien, el error está en querer tomar los valores de el formulario, eso es lo que no me funciona

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Metodo de bisecion</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>La funcion a iterar es: 6x^3-2x^2-x-1 = 0 en [0.5, 1]</h2><br><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

var n, an, fan, bn, fbn, pn, fpn;
n = 1;
an = parseFloat(document.getElementById("an").value);
bn = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bn").value);



//Comienza la iteracion
function biseccion(){

    do {

        pn = (an+bn)/2;


        fpn =Math.abs((6*(Math.pow(pn, 3))) - (2*(Math.pow(pn, 2))) - pn - 1);

        document.write(" | " + n + " | " + an + " | " + bn + " | " + pn + " | " + fpn + " | " + "<br><br>");

        fpn =(6*(Math.pow(pn, 3))) - (2*(Math.pow(pn, 2))) - pn - 1;

        fan =(6*(Math.pow(an, 3))) - (2*(Math.pow(an, 2))) - an - 1;

        if (fpn*fan > 0) {
            an = pn;
            bn = bn;
        }
        else if (fpn*fan < 0) {
            bn = pn;
            an = an;
        }

        else{

            alert("No se pudo determinar");
        }

        fpn =Math.abs((6*(Math.pow(pn, 3))) - (2*(Math.pow(pn, 2))) - pn - 1);

        n++;

    } while (fpn > 0.0001);

};

</script>

<!-- Formulario para ingresar intervalo de valores -->

<form>

a:<input type="text" id="an"><br><br>
b:<input type="text" id="bn"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Comenzar iteraciones" onclick="biseccion()">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tomas los valores de an y bn al inicio, pero no se actualiza, si pones las dos líneas con los getElementById dentro de la función, para que usen el valor en el momento de pulsar la tecla, debería funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! ya funciona pero solo para la primera iteracion!

Comment: Me refiero a dentro de la función, pero antes del bucle DO-WHILE, ya que se modifican los valores.

Comment: Toda la razón amigo, ya está corregido y funciona!!

Answer (score 2):

Es correcta la forma en que obtienes los valores:

```
valor = document.getElementById("an").value;
```

pero podrias definirlos dentro, cuando ejecutas tu funcion tomaria los valores, con eso seria suficiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Metodo de bisecion</title>
<script>




var n, an, fan, bn, fbn, pn, fpn;
n = 1;


//Comienza la iteracion
function biseccion(){

an = parseFloat(document.getElementById("an").value);
bn = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bn").value);

alert(an);
alert(bn);

    do {

        pn = (an+bn)/2;


        fpn =Math.abs((6*(Math.pow(pn, 3))) - (2*(Math.pow(pn, 2))) - pn - 1);

        document.write(" | " + n + " | " + an + " | " + bn + " | " + pn + " | " + fpn + " | " + "<br><br>");

        fpn =(6*(Math.pow(pn, 3))) - (2*(Math.pow(pn, 2))) - pn - 1;

        fan =(6*(Math.pow(an, 3))) - (2*(Math.pow(an, 2))) - an - 1;

        if (fpn*fan > 0) {
            an = pn;
            bn = bn;
        }
        else if (fpn*fan < 0) {
            bn = pn;
            an = an;
        }

        else{

            alert("No se pudo determinar");
        }

        fpn =Math.abs((6*(Math.pow(pn, 3))) - (2*(Math.pow(pn, 2))) - pn - 1);

        n++;

    } while (fpn > 0.0001);

};

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>La funcion a iterar es: 6x^3-2x^2-x-1 = 0 en [0.5, 1]</h2><br><br>

<form>

a:<input type="text" id="an"><br><br>
b:<input type="text" id="bn"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Comenzar iteraciones" onclick="biseccion()">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ahora sí!! le agradezco mucho! :D